# error: could not load or find main class xyz

Tags: java, jar

I have checked my java installations by compiling and running a HelloWorld program which works perfectly fine.
The problem comes when I compile my program with certain jar files which are located in the same directory as my java file. This is what I've done.

```
javac -cp "A.jar:B.jar" MyProg.java
```

This generates the class file `MyProg.class` successfully. Next when I run the following command, it gives this error `error: could not load or find main class MyProg`
The command is:

```
java -cp "A.jar:B.jar" MyProg
```

Next, I even tried next by moving the jars in a folder named `lib` and issued the following commands:

```
javac -cp "lib/*" MyProg.jar (works fine;generates a class file)
java -cp "lib/*" MyProg (issues the same error)
```

I am working on a linux machine. Can some one please resolve the error.

Comment: I have been stucked to this problem for a long time. So, if you are not interested to answer the question, please refrain yourself from giving a negative rating!

Comment: try `java -cp .;a.jar;b.jar MyProg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the current path to the classpath

```
java -cp .:A.jar:B.jar MyProg
```